# View Pager layouts not keep match parent after switch views

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-viewpager

I have four layouts inside of my viewpager that are supposed to match width/height of its parent (the viewpager). When the activity starts the first page appears to do that, but as soon as you swipe to the next one this weird gap appears. The gap will stay until the activity is restarted. How do I get rid of this gap?

Here's a video of what's happening: https://youtu.be/EA51HZuFruY

XML of one of the layouts (the other three are identical only having different background colors)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="@color/blue">


      <Button
         android:id="@+id/tab1_button"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_centerInParent="true"
         android:onClick="tab1Click"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Code for the viewpager's adapter

```
private class TabPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private ArrayList<Integer> layouts = new ArrayList<>();

    TabPagerAdapter() {
        layouts.add(R.layout.tab_menu_1);
        layouts.add(R.layout.tab_menu_2);
        layouts.add(R.layout.tab_menu_3);
        layouts.add(R.layout.tab_menu_4);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return layouts.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == (View) object;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View view = inflater.inflate(layouts.get(position), collection, false);
        collection.addView(view);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup collection, int position, Object view) {
        collection.removeView((View) view);
    }

}
```

**EDIT**: My layouts inside the viewpager are not matching parent if more than two views are in the viewpager. I can also tell it's not the viewpager not keeping it's constraints that I've given them.

**EDIT**: After about a month I figured out that changing the offscreen page limit to support the maximum number of screen that could ever be offscreen stops the problem. While I'd be fine with this it's causing slow down in the app, but maybe this might reveal the actually problem.

Comment: Remove `android:orientation="vertical"` from `RelativeLayout` tag.

Comment: @MuhammadHannan I already have and it doesn't fix the problem.